# How to put a script in the head tag in next.js?

Tags: typescript, next.js

I'm using next.js with `src/app` directory structure and as far as I understand, this structure doesn't support using `next/head`, so I have a question, how can I put the script and other tags for certain pages in the `<head></head>` tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the `layout.tsx` file at the root of the `app` folder you would typically add scripts there since you can have `<head>` tags inside.

If you need to add them on specific pages, you can directly use the [`Script`](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/components/script) component.

By default the `Script` component will use a `afterInteractive` strategy which would mean that you script would load after the page has been hydrated. In case you need the script to be in the head of the document you can always use [`beforeInteractive`](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/components/script#beforeinteractive) strategy which will always put the script on the head, no matter where in the component tree it will be located.